# Can a Facebook user determine which friends have installed an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a Facebook app and I'd like to reassure my app users that no one else will know they've installed the app. I don't even want a user's Facebook friends who also use the app to know s/he uses it. I basically want who uses the app to be completely private. (Obviously, I'll know they use it. And Facebook will. You know what I mean.)

Can someone verify that users won't be able to tell who else has installed the app, even if they start writing FB Graph queries or some such thing? Do I have to be careful to configure my app in any particular way to ensure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will only see a friend of the user, if both the user and the friend have granted your app `user_friends` permission.

Now a user could of course go and create an access token for your app, where they include user_friends permission. Won’t do them much good though, because they still won’t see any friends, because the friends did not grant the same permission on their part.

So you should be o.k. in that regard. It would require a user’s active participation for other friends to see them as a user of your app.

Go check the documentation chapter on login security and securing API requests, that has additional advice, such as requiring an app-secret proof for server-side API calls.

Comment: I'll need users to grant me (the app) the user_friends privilege, because I'd like to know if two users of my app are friends. (I just want to prevent each from knowing his friend is also a user. But I will know that.) I believe you're pointing out that without requiring an app secret, the user could get an access token (just like I can) and query /me/user_friends. So I need to require an app secret. But once I do, I should be good. That about right?

Comment: No, not really. The app-secret proof is only for server-side API calls – so a user could possibly make an API request using other means, such as the JS SDK, and still see who of their friends are users of the app. I think you have to decide here, what is more important – that your app can see user friends, _or_ that users won’t be able to do so. Both at the same time is likely not possible in a manner that is really “safe.”

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I would've thought that if you configure your app to require app-secret proof, the user can't acquire an access token for my app (unless I share the app secret). Is that right? I think that then presents a small problem -- ALL API calls would have to be server-side for the app. But that's not a killer, I think. Or I could even potentially have two app IDs, one with app-secret proof required and the not. Thanks for the thoughtful comments, BTW.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can get the online friends list which means friends who are all installed this app by using Graph request.

```
      if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("user_friends")){
        let request : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: nil,HTTPMethod: "GET")
        request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if((error == nil)){
             print(result)

            }else{
                print(error)
            }

        })
    }else{
        print("Publish action permission not granted")
    }
```